# File Operations Plugin fileCopyOperation - Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on File Operations Plugin- fileCopyOperation in Jenkins pipeline (Jenkins version - v2.73.2 ,Jenkins pipeline - 2.5) i need to copy file from one location to the other location with different folder structure.

Expected:

### Source

C:\workspace\Hello -> xxx,yyy [xxx directory contains sub-directories and files aaa,bbb,ccc.txt; yyy dir contains web.xml,sec.txt]

### Destination

F:\Test\Sample -> aaa,bbb,ccc.txt
F:\Test\Example -> web.xml,sec.txt

Below is the command i am using which is copying whole Hello directory not the way it is behaving as expected.

```
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '',
                                  flattenFiles: false,
                                  includes: 'C:\workspace\Hello\**',
                                  targetLocation: 'F:\Test\Sample')])
```

### Present:

F:\Test\Sample\workspace\Hello -> xxx,yyy

Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

```
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '',
                                  flattenFiles: false,
                                  includes: 'C:\workspace\Hello\**',
                                  targetLocation: 'F:\Test\Sample')])
```

You have mention the below line which is telling to taking everything i.e. xxx,yyy folders so its doing it's job correctly

> C:\workspace\Hello**

you will have to mention in the excludes section which folder to exclude i.e. yyy in this case.

For simplicity's sake

```
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '',
                                  flattenFiles: false,
                                  includes: 'C:\workspace\Hello\xxx\**',
                                  targetLocation: 'F:\Test\Sample')])
```

The above copies from xxx folder to F:\Test\Sample and the below copies from yyy folder to F:\Test\Example

```
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '',
                                  flattenFiles: false,
                                  includes: 'C:\workspace\Hello\yyy\**',
                                  targetLocation: 'F:\Test\Example')])
```

Comment: @Sri  if this helped you in solving your issue please select it as the correct answer so that others, who face this issue will know what needs to be done

Comment: Thanks for the reply and apologize for responding late. This makes sense, however, its actually copying files in folder structure as F:\Test\Sample\workspace\Hello\xxx\**  but expected is to copy files direct to the F:\Test\Sample\**

Comment: @Sri I think that's an existing issue as mentioned here in the comments https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin ... Why not use a simple 'cp' command to achieve what you want